# Why Future<> result from ApiProxy.Delegate.makeAsyncCall() is never used?

Tags: google-app-engine, hook, google-cloud-datastore

I'm playing with GAE hooks and trying to follow [Nick's blog post](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/App-Engine-Java-API-call-hooks). But apparently it's somewhat outdated because it doesn't have implementation of `makeAsyncCall` which exists in my GAE SDK 1.6.1.

Here is snippet of my code

```
public class MultiTenantHook implements Delegate
{
    @Override
    public Future<byte[]> makeAsyncCall(final Environment env, final String pkgName, final String method, final byte[] request, ApiProxy.ApiConfig config)
    {
        Callable<byte[]> callable = new Callable<byte[]>()
        {
            @Override
            public byte[] call() throws Exception
            {
                return makeSyncCall(env, pkgName, method, request);
            }
        };

        FutureTask<byte[]> task = new FutureTask<byte[]>(callable);
        return task;
    }
}
```

This method is being called but returned `Future<>` is never used by GAE. `call()` method of inner class is never executed.

Do you know how to make it work?

Comment: I haven't been able to find the javadoc of these classes. But a Future is typically returned when submitting a Callable to some thread executor. If you never submit your callable to anything, no thread will ever call it.

Comment: What do you mean by "submitting" it ?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html. There must be some similar interface or even an implementation of this interface is GAE's API.